# How to fulfill libcdio-cdda0 dependency of SKG Jukebox?

Tags: software-installation, dependencies

I am trying to install SKG Jukebox onto an old netbook (ASUS Aspire One) with Ubuntu installed on it. It says that there is a dependency for `libcdio-cdda0` . But I cant work out how to add that.

Also this netbook is old and slow, and idealy I would like it to book into just a command line and then run skg in the hopes that it will run a bit quicker, is this possible?

Further info as requested:

I am downloading the debian package from here: http://www.skgsoft.net/downloads

The response from running `lsb_release`:

```
No LSB modules are available
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS
Release: 12.04
Codename: Precise
```

I am trying to install it by clicking on the downloaded .deb and it takes me to Ubuntu Software Centre and that's were it says there is a dependency.

When I run `apt-cache policy` to get information about the package, I get:

```
N: unable to locate package libcdio-cdda0
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no package `libcdio-cdda0` in the [officially Ubuntu repositories](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=precise&arch=any&searchon=names&keywords=libcdio).

Simply install `libcdio-cdda1`

```
sudo apt-get install libcdio-cdda1
```

Comment: @Chromedome: As you're a reputation 1 user: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**